# Integration over sphere in terms of integration over disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

In the wave equation section of evans pde we have the following
[image]

Can anyone explain why the jacobian term is $1+D\gamma(y) $?

Comment: I'm guessing the $\tilde{B}$ and $B$ represent balls of different dimensions? Do you know how $dS$ is defined/ related to the square root of the gram matrix?

Comment: Yes they are of different dimension, 3 and 2 respectively. And I dont think I know how dS is  defined in that way @peek-a-boo

Comment: very roughly speaking it's the higher dimensional analogue of the fact that the length of the graph of a function $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb{R}$ can be computed as $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx$. So if we have more independent variables, say $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, the surface area of the graph "over a region $\Omega$" is generalized to $\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right)^2}\, d^nx = \int_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+|Df(x)|^2}\,d^nx$

Comment: Ok I see, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just elaborating slightly on the case where there are two independent variables. Suppose $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ is a given function. Then the idea is that if you have a rectangle $A=[x_0,x_0+\Delta x]\times [y_0,y_0+\Delta y]$ in the domain, then the image $f(A)$ will be a deformed/curved rectangle which we imagine as a curved rectangular surface lying over our original rectangle $A$.

Now the question is how can we approximate the area of $f(A)$. Well we approximate our surface $f(A)$ via its tangent plane at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. Then, we have the corresponding vectors
\begin{align}
\xi_1=\Delta x\cdot\left(1,0,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\right) \quad \text{and}\quad
\xi_2=\Delta y\cdot\left(0,1,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right)
\end{align}
which are tangent to the surface $f(A)$ (in other words, we are taking the tangent vectors $(\Delta x,0)$ and $(0,\Delta y)$ to the rectangle $A$ and looking at the corresponding tangent vectors $\xi_1,\xi_2$ on the image $f(A)$). Now, if the rectangle $A$ is small enough, then the plane spanned by these two vectors ought to approximate $f(A)$ well. So, we can approximate the area of $f(A)$ by the area of the parallelogram spanned by the two vectors $\xi_1,\xi_2$. But if you recall, the area of a parallelogram is the absolute value of the cross product:
\begin{align}
\text{area } f(A) &\approx \text{area spanned by $\xi_1,\xi_2$}\\
&=|\xi_1\times \xi_2|\\
&=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\right)^2+
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right)^2}\cdot |\Delta x\Delta y|
\end{align}
In higher dimensions, one would of course need an analogous formula for the $k$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $k$ vectors (this is ultimately related to the gram matrix I mentioned in the comments). Anyway, hopefully this gives you a better intuition for why the surface area of a graph is as such.